# Screen hangs while capturing Qrcode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, qr-code

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app which requires Qrcode scannig and I am using Zxing library for scanning Qr codes.

In this app I need get back to the previous page once the scan is finished.

I am using the code below,

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{

    _phoneCamera = new PhotoCamera();
    _phoneCamera.Initialized += cam_Initialized;
    _phoneCamera.AutoFocusCompleted += _phoneCamera_AutoFocusCompleted;

    CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed += CameraButtons_ShutterKeyHalfPressed;

    viewfinderBrush.SetSource(_phoneCamera);

    _scanTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _scanTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500);
    _scanTimer.Tick += (o, arg) => ScanForBarcode();

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    _scanTimer.Stop();
    if (cameraInit)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
           {                       
               if (_phoneCamera != null)
               {
                   _phoneCamera.CancelFocus();
                   _phoneCamera.Dispose();                        
                   _phoneCamera.Initialized -= cam_Initialized;
                   _phoneCamera = null;
                   cameraInit = false;
               }
           });
    }
}

void cam_Initialized(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Succeeded)
    {
        cameraInit = true;
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {                 
           _phoneCamera.FlashMode = FlashMode.Auto;
            _previewBuffer = new WriteableBitmap((int)_phoneCamera.PreviewResolution.Width, (int)_phoneCamera.PreviewResolution.Height);
            _barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

          (int)_phoneCamera.PreviewResolution.Width, (int)_phoneCamera.PreviewResolution.Height, 0, 100);

            var supportedBarcodeFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
            supportedBarcodeFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
            supportedBarcodeFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX);
            _barcodeReader.Options.PossibleFormats = supportedBarcodeFormats;

            _barcodeReader.Options.TryHarder = true;               
            _barcodeReader.ResultFound += _bcReader_ResultFound;
            _scanTimer.Start();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to initialize the camera");
        });
    }

}


void _bcReader_ResultFound(Result obj)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        VibrateController.Default.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        a = obj.Text;
        _scanTimer.Stop();
        NavigationService.GoBack(); //here I am going back to previos page
    });
}

private void ScanForBarcode()
{                    
    _phoneCamera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(_previewBuffer.Pixels);
    _previewBuffer.Invalidate();
    _barcodeReader.Decode(_previewBuffer);         
}
```

This code working fine but some times while capturing the qrcode it hangs the application.

EDITED

This problem occurs when I run the application without debugging mode.
And when the application become unresponsive, after sometime it crashes but does not give any error message.

So please help me to solve this issue. Thanks In advance.

Comment: Define "hangs".  Does the app become unresponsive for a period, or does it crash?  Is there a related error message?

Comment: It become unresponsive and it crashes after sometime but it does not show any error message. I edited my question now....

Comment: @user2428823 Did you get it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but Is it possible that you are trying to scan the QR Code on the UI thread thus causing the hang. Try doing it on a different thread for it.

The Windows Phone OS doesn't like a unresponsive UI thread and might cause the application to close unexpectedly.